# Were the memories fabricated or modified?

Tags: rick-and-morty

In S2E4 of *Rick & Morty*, *Total Rickall*, the alien parasites mess with the family's memories to insert themselves into the family's history.  However, a detail of this is a little unclear to me.  We see plenty of memories that are largely realistic, except we see the alien parasite character inserted, placed in a key role.

Are these memories entirely fabricated, or did the alien parasites just modify existing memories, inserting themselves into them?

Comment: Difficult to come up with a consistent answer, given the ending.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but they must be modified. There are unpleasant circumstances where the parasites saved them. Could they fabricate the unpleasant parts as long as it works out?

Answer (score 5):

Completely fabricated:

> Morty: I figured it out, Rick. The parasites can only **create** pleasant memories.

The first episode of season two tells us just how sure of himself Rick is, and I don't doubt that what he says is correct about him buying 3DS systems:

> Rick: Okay, yes. I definitely remember doing that. But also, I would never do that.

So sure of himself, he must be, that even this doesn't convince him to start shooting family members. After all, there's a hundred percent chance of the possibility that in this universe, he *did* do that.

Ok, yea: he tried to wing Summer - but we're not here to point out plot inconsistencies. Besides he's, *"not used to being this unsure for this long."* It's probably at this point he realizes that's the only thing he's sure of, which belays any further action.

Regarding the ending, we have to look at

> the modified intro sequence that shows Mr. Poopybutthole in some decidedly unpleasant memories, the only pleasant one includes Mr. Beauregard.

Comment: Jesus christ that was a great deal on Nintendo DS systems, if that happened near me, I buy some DS, flip them on eBay and then keep one for myself.... Nintendeo give me free *burrrrp* stuff